# Color excel pivot columns based by column header

Tags: excel, pivot, background-color

I would like to change background colors on the columns in my pivot table based on the header (dimension on the X-axis).

When i click "Banded colums" it just colors every secon column, but i want the behavior from the last table in my example below. It should change every time the year is changing.

In the example the columns are always grouped in pairs two and two, but a solution that can handle variable column-sets would be perfect.

Any suggestions?

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XjhuC.png)

Answer (score 1):

Now I understand, I totally misread your question.

- Right-click one of the pivottable styles you like and select "Duplicate".
- Give the style a meaningful name
- Click the First Column stripe item
- Set Stripe size to 2
- Click the Second Column stripe item
- Set Stripe size to 2
- OK
- Click the PivotTable Styles dropdown and select your newly added style.
- Check "Banded columns"

Comment: Thanks, it works for this report because i always have 2 columns, 

but i would love a more generic solution with background change everytime i get a new attribute on the x-axis (in this case Year).

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to use a conditional format. Home, Conditional formatting.
Suppose you want to highlight all columns which have "#Rolls":

- Select all data columns in the PT, for example cells B4:I20
- Click Home, Conditional formatting, New Rule
- Select "Use a formula to determine which cells to format"
- Enter this formula: =B$4="#Rolls"
- Choose the appropriate format by clicking the format button and setting things up.
- OK your way back to Excel

Comment: Could you please explain how in the example?

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but that does not help. I only colors the columns with the header "#Rolls". I want it to color every second year (column B,C,F,G).

Comment: Darn, this isn't my best series of answers ever I guess :-) The way to go about this is as follows: Turn on "Repeat al item labels" in the Report Layout dropdown so each column shows the year. Add a conditional format to the data section of the Pivottable using this formule: =ISEVEN(B$2). For the "Aply rule to", use All Cells showing... (second option).